Can you make Visual Studio launch the web browser for a Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker startup project?
I have a Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker startup project which is a kind of bootstrap project that sorts out DI and runs a couple of hosts, one of which is a web server.  I therefore want Visual Studio to open the web browser at a certain localhost URL when I debug that startup project.  However, this launchSettings.json doesn't cause the web browser to be opened:
{
  "profiles": {
    "ExcaliburBotDEV": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "/abc",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5111/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "DOTNET_URLS": "https://0.0.0.0:5111;http://0.0.0.0:5110"
      }
    },
    "ExcaliburBotPROD": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "/abc",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5111/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Production",
        "DOTNET_URLS": "https://0.0.0.0:5111;http://0.0.0.0:5110"
      }
    }
  }
}

As far as I can tell the only reason for this is that my startup project isn't actually a web project.  When I manually load https://localhost:5111/ in the web browser the web interface loads fine.  Is there any way I can get Visual Studio to launch the browser at a certain URL anyway?
